# SharePoint adding -Grp to the end of site names

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, rename

I've made a couple of sites on SharePoint before, but now when I try to edit the name of one or create a new one, SharePoint says the name is available in my organization, but then appends "-Grp" to the end of the name. For instance, if I name the site "My New SP Site," SharePoint says that is available, but then names the site "My New SP Site-Grp" instead.

I've never seen this before. Does anyone know why it's doing this or how I can stop it from appending to the ends of site names? I tried researching the issue but haven't found any similar cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to someone implementing the [Office 365 Group Naming Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/groups-naming-policy). Talk to your Azure administrators about this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... I will ask our admins about this and come back to accept your answer if it solves the issue.